# How to hide images based on src 301 redirect URL attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can hide all images with matching src attribute using a CSS3 attribute selector.  For example:

```
img[src*="photo_unavailable"] {
display: none;
}
```

will hide images with src containing "photo_unavailable".

However, what about an image like this:

```
https://farm7.static.flickr.com/6180/6172064687_834c859b5c_b.jpg
```

which redirects to:

```
https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/en-us/photo_unavailable_l.png
```

Is there a way to hide the image based on a string "photo_unavailable" found in the redirected src?

Comment: Anything is possible, but you probably have to write some serverside code that checks the urls for a 301 redirect response.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Because the `src` attribute correspond to the "broken" image link, not the "photo_unavailable" link.

Answer (score -2):

It can be tricki - just put your image inside a element

HTML

```
 <a href="https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/en-us/photo_unavailable_l.png" >
      <img src="https://farm7.static.flickr.com/6180/6172064687_834c859b5c_b.jpg"/>
    </a>
```

CSS

```
a[href*="photo_unavailable"] > img  , img[src*="photo_unavailable"]  {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: redirect won't change the `src`. Try it yourself